# What kind of headphones are appropriate for a Skype interview?

Tags: interviewing

One of the initial interviews is often a Skype interview. Audio and video quality are important. What should I keep in mind when setting up my audio devices for a Skype interview?

I think speakers are out of the window, as I do not want to create an echo effect, so I decided to go with headphones. I have a few different kinds of headphones. Big over-ear gaming ones with a good microphone in them, simple looking over-ear Bose ones and simple white earbuds.

Are there any expectations regarding headphones? Are gaming headphones not done? Are over-ear headphones less professional than earbuds? Or is this all a matter of opinion?

**What should I keep in mind when deciding on headphones for a Skype interview?**

Comment: Why do you think speakers are out of the window? If by "echo effect" you mean audio feedback, there won't be any. If you're just worried about sound quality, it won't be anything significant.

Comment: I think MS has figured out how to fix the echo. That said, I love my Jimi Hendrix headset with cords that don't tangle!

Comment: "Big over-ear gaming ones with a good microphone in them" - I would suggest against headphones with a boom mic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a technical question concerning audio hardware. Said hardware being used for an interview is not sufficient reason to make it on-topic here. The only answer this community is truly qualified to give is "use headphones that work."

Comment: For travel I've got little Microsoft headsets with microphone that fold up and fit into a compact bag. I rarely do video, but it's unobtrusive looking if that matters. It works very nicely as long as the Skype connection is good, and if it isn't no headset is going to help.

Comment: @Lilienthal by that reasoning questions about what to wear to interviews should also be off-topic, but they aren't.

Comment: @J.Constantine Business casual and dress code are typical workplace concepts but we still don't do fashion advice on this site. A purchase advice thread for headphones isn't suitable for our audience. Even if we were to assume that less "professional" headphones would have an impact, which they almost certainly don't, then no comprehensive answer could be given as each industry and region would have different standards. The only useful pointers we could give are: A) make sure they work, and B) don't have a swastika on them. Your question is too broad and too far removed from the workplace.

Comment: Note that if you want to debate this further, please make a thread on meta to discuss whether this question fits our topics and posting guidelines.

Comment: Unfortunately, echo can always be a concern--and can change during any given call. The Skype echo canceler is somewhat aggressive, so it butchers the audio, or worse, adds a long lag. That long lag makes turn-taking hard, which can kill an interview. Use headphones for anything important.

Comment: I put my $0.02 in over here:  http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/55056/9264

Answer (score 7):

As someone who has had several Skype interviews I think you're *way* overthinking it. As long as the sound quality is reasonably good and the headphones aren't decorated with obscene gestures it's highly unlikely anyone would care in the slightest. **Wear whatever makes you most comfortable.**

Comment: I use regular earbuds with my laptop's built-in speaker, which gives decent sound quality, while not making me look like an airplane pilot with big over the ear headphones with a boom mic (as I've seen some people do).

Comment: I do think wearing huge head phones might look a little silly. Wearing simple ear buds sound more reasonable than wearing huge bose head sets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just not hip enough to feel comfortable being seen with headphones on during an interview. Test out your system with some friends and see if the echo is a concern at all.

You'd also have to make sure you can control your voice. Even though you can hear it through Skype, some people aren't very good at it. Again, practice with a friend.

Comment: Practice is good. Also, one thing I like to do on skype is look at the camera if you can, and not the person on the screen. That gives the appearance of eye contact.